# HDFS memory not deleting when table dropped HIVE

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hdfs, ambari

Hi I am relatively new to HIVE and HDFS so apologies in advance if I am not wording this correctly.
I have used Microsoft Azure to create a virtual machine. I am then logging into this using putty and Ambari Sandbox.

In Ambari I am using HIVE, all is working fine but I am having major issues with memory allocation. 
When I drop a table in Hive I will then go into my 'Hive View' and delete the table from the trash folder. However this is freeing up no memory within the HDFS.

The table is now gone from my HIVE database and also from the trash folder but no memory has been freed.

Is there somewhere else where I should be deleting the table from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not "memory", it's disk space. What exactly are you checking?...

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, as @DuduMarkovitz said, I also don't know what  `HDFS memory` you said is, but I think that you want to say is the table data files on HDFS.

Per my experience, I think the table you dropped in Hive is an external table, not an internal table. You can get the feature below from Hive offical document for [`External Tables`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables).

> **External Tables**
>   The EXTERNAL keyword lets you create a table and provide a LOCATION so that Hive does not use a default location for this table. This comes in handy if you already have data generated. ***When dropping an EXTERNAL table, data in the table is NOT deleted from the file system.***

The difference between interal table and external table, you can refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2013/02/05/hdinsight-hive-internal-and-external-tables-intro/).

So if you want to recycle the external table data from HDFS after dropped the external table, you need to use the commend below for HDFS to remove it manually.

```
hadoop fs -rm -f -r <your-hdfs-path-url>/apps/hive/warehouse/<database name>/<table-name>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, unfortunetly I have deleted the table using the hadoop fs -rm -f -r <your-hdfs-path-url>/apps/hive/warehouse/<database name>/<table-name> but the memory in HDFS is still at capacity. Where I am seeing that the memory is full is in the Summary section and Disk Usage (Non DFS Used) is 18.8GB/42GB. This should have dropped by 9GB when I removed the deleted table from trash. Disk Usage (DFS Used) is at 15.8 GB and from what I understand this can not be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table_name>` command. It should show you location of file in HDFS. Check if this location is empty.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. The table has been dropped so this command won't work. However I have used in on a table in the same database and it points me in the direction of apps/hive/warehouse/<database name>/<table name>. But this is where the table I dropped was before I deleted it and the dropped table is no longer there.